# Should you be able to be flagged as duplicate by newer post?

Tags: bug, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

[This happened to me.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95572/balefire-suicide) And I think it is a bug that it COULD even happen. A user saw my question and spawned a similar question (a more general question). After a user saw the newer question and then read mine, my question was flagged as a duplicate.

Obviously it was not a duplicate since it was the original question. Any protection against this kind of thing in the future?

Comment: Wow...now I am guilty of the same thing...this...is...embarassing.

Comment: I love the meta-ness of the title!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have always been able to close an older post as a duplicate of a newer one. It's generally done that way if the newer post is significantly better, especially if it gets better answers, or if the newer post is more general and encompasses the older one.